# mailto -link not launching on iOS Web App

Tags: ios, web-applications

I'm trying to launch a link with href="mailto:foo@bar.com" (also tried "mailto://foo@bar.com"). When I alert `this.href`, it returns the correct value, but nothing happens afterwards.

Is there a custom URL Scheme for Web Applications to launch Mail-program? This is working eg. with Maps, so I have no idea why same approach wouldn't work with E-mail.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from Apple's iPhone URL scheme guide:

[image]

Comment: I had read the same guide. And I got it working now, there were couple of smaller problems that affected on the situation (including I had forgotten it as a DIV element whilst testing :)).

Comment: Note that this works on an actual device, not on the simulator

Comment: FYI - Found an edge case where a user who has deleted the iOS Mail app in favor of the Gmail app has nothing launched. Instead an error modal comes up asking if you'd like to download the Mail app from the App Store. This may be better UX when iOS 14 is released, which they say will allow for changing the default mail and browser apps from Apple's native apps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm finding that this seems to work well with iOS in web-app mode. Works for **MAILTO:** and **SMS:** links that otherwise gave an error. Also does **not** open a new blank page like some "solutions".

```html
<a href='#' onclick='window.open(`mailto:mail@example.com`, `_self`);'>Link text</a>
```