# How to invoke E-mail application?

Tags: ios, email, invoke

How to invokeE-mail application by code in ios system? I want to check email interface rather than sending mail interface.

Thanks.

Comment: both are totally different question what you mean possibly duplicate? just bother to read full question

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of this:

```
- (void)launchMailAppOnDevice
{
    NSMutableString *subject  = [NSMutableString string];
    [subject appendString:@"Your Subject"];

    NSMutableString *mailbody  = [NSMutableString string];
    [mailbody appendString:@"Blah Blah Blah"];
    [mailbody appendString:@"Blah Blah Blah "];

    NSString *recipients = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"mailto:test@test.com?&subject=%@!",subject];

    NSString *body = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"&body=%@!",mailbody];;

    NSString *emailString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", recipients, body];

    emailString = [emailString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:email]];
}
```

If you want to check whether mail app is present int app and you want to open it.

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[ NSURL URLWithString:@"mailto:"]]) 
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"mailto:"]];
```

Comment: I want to check email interface rather than sending mail interface. Do you have a good idear? Thanks

Comment: @user2297463 Do you want to check whether device has mail application or device can send mail. Please be clear, I think I can help you.

Comment: See my edit, you can open your mail app using the last two statements.

Comment: I'm sorry ,my question may be not clear.Your code only open the send mail interface,but I want to open the email interface,that is the mailbox interface. Be clear?

Answer (score 0):

MFMailComposeViewController is an official API that you can use to *compose* messages from within your app.

[I've heard you can use the "`mailto:`" URL scheme to open the Mail application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9225351/mailto-link-not-launching-on-ios-web-app) and compose a message from there (assuming the Mail app is still installed on your iOS device, that is), but this is only supposed for composing a message from within the mail app, it doesn't switch the user to the inbox.

Comment: Yes ,you are right.But I need to invoke the email app rather than composing a message from within the mail app now.Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can't open mail app. All you can do it open the compose e-mail interface using either `MFMailComposeViewController` or `mailto:` URL.